# What exactly is a variable template

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++14

I am getting c++11 warnings about variable templates.  I'm not entirely sure that I need them, because I'm not entirely sure what they are.  [References that I've found](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/5894415f-be62-4bc0-81c5-3956e82276f3/entry/Introduction_to_Variable_Templates_of_C_14?lang=en) don't bother defining the term before using it. My immediate thought was that it was an attempt to declare a variable that is of the templated type `T`, but this code compiles fine:

```
template <class T>
image<T> *image<T>::copy() const {
  image<T> *im = new image<T>(w, h, false);
  memcpy(im->data, data, w * h * sizeof(T));
  return im;
}
```

What is a thorough definition of a variable template, and why does this NOT have a variable template problem

Comment: Here you go: [Variable template](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variable_template). Use [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/).

Comment: I saw this site as well, and didn't find it particularly helpful.  It gives "A variable template defines a family of variables or static data members." and a couple of examples.  The code in my example seems, to me, to be a further example based on the limited info in the definition on cppreference.  Why is it not?

Comment: This does not look like a variable template, more like a member function template.

Comment: Of note is that `image<T>` is declared and defined earlier.  Is that the redeeming quality here?

Comment: I'm not suggesting that I shouldn't use cppreference.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A class template is a template that defines a series of classes, based on one or more template parameters. A function template is a template that defines a series of functions, based on one or more template parameters. `vector` is a template class; `vector<int>` is a specific class instantiated from that template.

A variable template is therefore a template that defines a series of *variables*, based on one or more template parameters:

```
template<typename T>
T variable_name{};
```

That is a variable template. You would specify which one you want just like any other template: `variable_name<int>` will be of type `int`. `variable_name` is a *template*; `variable_name<int>` is actually a variable.

Of course, you can do more complex things:

```
template<typename T>
vector<T> vector_var{};
```

`vector_var<int>` is a `vector<int>`.

Variable templates can only be introduced at namespace/global scope and as static members of classes. At namespace/global scope, they're usually declared `constexpr` (and/or in C++17, `inline`). They're useful for making constants:

```
template<typename T>
inline constexpr bool is_default_constructible_v = std::is_default_constructible<T>::value;
```

So if you want to tell if something is default constructible, you don't need the slightly awkward `::value` syntax.

Variable templates are a C++14 feature, which is why your compiler probably warned you about using them in a C++11 mode.

---

> ```
> image<T> *im = new image<T>(w, h, false);
> ```

This is *not* a variable template. This is a regular variable whose type is very well defined: `image<T>`. There is exactly one variable named "`im`". You don't use `im<T>` to get a variable.

That statement does not define a family of variables. What you have is a family of *functions*, where each of them *contain* a variable called `im`. The function is the template here, not the variable.

Comment: This is clearer.  My specific offending code is a function parameter: `std::unordered_map<T,int> *counter`  It seems to me that this has the same format at declaring `image<T> *im`...

Comment: @Scott: Your question was "what is a variable template", not "why does this code give a warning about variable templates?" If that's what you want to know, you should ask that question. But don't change this one. And if you do ask that question, provide the code that reproduces the problem, as well as the compiler you're using (with the compiler's version number) and compiler switches.

Comment: I haven't changed the question at all.  Indeed, it seemed to me that the question was better as "what is a variable template", so I left it as is, and mentioned my continued confusion as a comment.

Comment: I cleared up some other errors, and the 'variable template' error around `std::unordered_map<T,int> *counter` just went away.  Apparently I didn't have a problem with variable templates, but knowing what they are helped me solve my problem.